# Definition of derivative as a slope: is a slope a function?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definition

I'm trying to understand the definition of derivative as a slope.

The definition is as follows:

> Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ be a function defined, at least, on an interval centered at $a$. The derivative of $f$ at $a$ is the number:
>
> $$f'(a) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a}$$

When I learned about limits, I learned that they apply to functions. How come it also applies to a slope?

I was thinking that maybe a slope can be interpreted as a function with four inputs, like this:

> $$m(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2) = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$

Is that a valid interpretation?

Comment: That fraction/slope is a function of $x$.

Comment: Your function $m$ doesn’t tell us the slope of anything directly, it’s just a way of approximating the slope between $x_1$ and $x_2$. (Also it doesn’t need to take in $y_1$ and $y_2$ since those are just $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ already determined by the function you’re finding the slope of). The limit in the normal definition of the derivative just says “what value do we approach as we take better and better approximations of the slope at a given point $x$?”.

Comment: @Randall How would I express the fraction/slope as a function? Would it be $g(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the correct expression for the slope of the line through $(a,f(a))$ and $(x,f(x))$. The derivative $f'(a)$ is the limit of all those slopes as $x \to a$.

Comment: Thank you, it's starting to make sense now

Comment: @JackCrawford I don't fully understand what you mean by "directly" and "approximation". Does $g(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ tell us the slope of something directly? But thanks for clarifying that $y_1$ and $y_2$ aren't needed, you are right of course. Also, what is the "normal" definition of derivative? Is it the one I posted?

Comment: The only thing that $g(x)$ will tell us is the best linear approximation of the slope — if you use it on any curved function, it will draw a line directly between two points on the function and tell you the slope of that line, which is not the same thing as the slope of the function. Of course, the smaller the distance between the two points, the closer your $g(x)$ approximation will actually be to the real slope of the function. The limit/derivative is the only thing that gives us the true slope of the function.

Comment: $g(x)$ is the slope of the secant line through the points  $(a,f(a))$ and $(x,f(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, 
$$
f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)
$$
where
$$
g(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}.
$$
Note that $g(x)$ is the slope of the line through the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(x,f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking that maybe a slope can be interpreted as a function
>   with four inputs

The equations you put are correct, except that the slope is usually not written as a function of four variables (by convention). In cases, it may require 4 parameters to get its value. The slope is defined as:"*the slope or gradient of a line is a number that describes both the direction and the steepness of the line*".

The equation of the a line with slope m is:

$$y=mx+b$$

The following picture is important. It is fundamental in learning Calculus. Almost any decent Calculus book will have a fancy illustration of these facts.

[image]

Sources:

[Wiki-Slope Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)

[Image Source-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29Px0qXE1BU)